# Simple SVM in MATLAB

Tags: machine-learning, matlab

I'm studying [SVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine) and wrote a demo in MATLAB (because I couldn't get a quadratic programming package to work correctly in Python). Right now it's simple and can only do linearly-separable cases (nonlinear kernels will be implemented later). This is the first MATLAB program I've written outside of a MATLAB seminar I'm taking, so any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
% simple SVM demo
clc;clear all;

% input data; y's are labels for data
y = [ -1; -1; -1; -1; -1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1 ];
data = [
    0 3;
    1 2;
    2 1;
    3 3;
    5 1;
    5 5;
    6 5;
    6 7;
    7 3;
    8 6;
    8 1;
];

% separate positive and negative datapoints
posDps = data(find(y == 1), :);
negDps = data(find(y == -1), :);

% space is number of dimensions (n-space)
% right now, b/c being plotted in 2D, can only be 2-space
space = size(data, 2);
% n is number of input variables
n = length(data);
[ y1, y2 ] = meshgrid(y, y);
[ i, j ] = meshgrid(1:n, 1:n);

% generate matrices for minimization
P(i, j) = y1(i, j) .* y2(i, j) .* (data(i,:) * data(j,:)');
q = -1 * ones(n, 1);

% generate matrices for inequality constraint (alpha >= 0)
% also can use LB parameter
A = -1 * eye(n);
b = zeros(n, 1);

% generate matrices for equality constraint
Aeq = y';
beq = [ 0 ];

% use quadprog package to generate alphas
alpha = quadprog(P, q, A, b, Aeq, beq, [], [], [], optimoptions('quadprog', 'Display', 'off'));
% calculate w from alpha
w = (data' .* repmat(y', [space 1])) * alpha;

% finding b parameter
% (y_n)(x_n * w + b) = 1 for support vector, so b = y_n - w * x_n
threshold = 1e-5;
svIndices = find(alpha > threshold);
b = y(svIndices(1)) - data(svIndices(1),:) * w;

% display points
figure;
hold on;
scatter(posDps(:,1), posDps(:,2));
scatter(negDps(:,1), negDps(:,2));

% draw line (only 2D for now)
margin = 1;
domain = (min(data(:,1)) - margin):(max(data(:,1)) + margin);
plot(domain, (w(1) .* domain + b)/(-w(2)));

% plotting gutters
plot(domain, (-1 + w(1) .* domain + b)/(-w(2)), 'g:');
plot(domain, (1 + w(1) .* domain + b)/(-w(2)), 'g:');
```

I'd like any feedback, but here are some specific questions I had in mind:

1. For storing one-dimensional data (arrays), is there usually a preference between column and row matrices?
2. Is there an easy way to deal with nested matrices? I tried to combine the labels and attribute vectors like so:

   ```
   data = [
       -1 [ 0 3 ];
       -1 [ 1 2 ];
       % ...
   ]
   ```

   and use more indices (e.g., `data(1,2,2)`) but that didn't work.
3. There are a ton of different ways to create matrices, and I'm not sure if the ones I am using are the most appropriate (e.g., via literals, `find()`, `meshgrid()`, `ones()` and `zeros()`, `repmat()`, etc.).
4. What is there to do about arbitrary imprecision? For example, I had to put in an arbitrary value `threshold` to find non-zero values because using `find(A > 0)` wasn't working. (Since the values were on the magnitude of about 1e-12, this was larger than the value of `eps()` so that function didn't seem very helpful.)
5. Naming conventions -- is there one for MATLAB? I don't believe I've seen a consistent style.

Comment: I'm new to Code Review.SE, so if there's anything I'm doing wrong that I should fix (off-topic, additional info, etc.) please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to answer your specific questions:

> 1. For storing one-dimensional data (arrays), is there usually a preference between column and row matrices?

It doesn't matter, use what is most convenient. Often horizontal vectors are used because they are easy to create: `1:10`.

> 2. Is there an easy way to deal with nested matrices?

The best way to collect matrices is using [a cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). A cell array's elements are arbitrary values (matrices, other cell arrays, objects, function handles, whatever you can assign to a variable).

> 3. There are a ton of different ways to create matrices, and I'm not sure if the ones I am using are the most appropriate (e.g., via literals, `find()`, `meshgrid()`, `ones()` and `zeros()`, `repmat()`, etc.).

Yes, MATLAB has a huge library and it is impossible to know if you are using the best possible function in each case. Experience will help.

> 4. What is there to do about arbitrary imprecision? For example, I had to put in an arbitrary value threshold to find non-zero values because using `find(A > 0)` wasn't working. (Since the values were on the magnitude of about 1e-12, this was larger than the value of `eps()` so that function didn't seem very helpful.)

Yes, you need to pick some threshold there. It depends on the source of the data what an appropriate value is. `eps` is the distance between `1.0` and the next representable floating-point value. That is, there are no possible values in between `1.0` and `1.0+eps`. `eps` is not necessarily an appropriate threshold to find "approximately zero" values.

> 5. Naming conventions -- is there one for MATLAB? I don't believe I've seen a consistent style.

Not that I know of. Early versions of MATLAB were not case sensitive, so all code was typically written in lower case. Currently some built-in functionality uses an upper case for the first letter, and some use camelCase. There is no PEP8 for MATLAB. :)

---

Now I'll go through the bits of code that can be improved:

> ```
> clc;clear all;
> ```

Please use the MATLAB Editor, and heeds its warnings. `clear all` is not useful here, it not only clears variables, it also clears functions from memory. These will need to be read in and parsed again, slowing down your program. `clear` suffices to remove variables from your workspace.

> ```
> posDps = data(find(y == 1), :);
> negDps = data(find(y == -1), :);
> ```

Here you can remove `find`. The MATLAB Editor also warns about this.

```
posDps = data(y == 1, :);
negDps = data(y == -1, :);
```

`find` is usually not necessary when indexing, only when you need to store an index to an array element.

> ```
> space = size(data, 2);
> n = length(data);
> ```

It is always better to specify directly what size you need. `length(data)` is defined as `max(size(data))`, I consider this dangerous. Instead:

```
[n,space] = size(data);
```

or

```
space = size(data, 2);
n = size(data, 1);
```

You should also know `numel`, which returns the number of elements in a matrix. This is much more efficient than `prod(size(data))`.

> ```
> [ y1, y2 ] = meshgrid(y, y);
> [ i, j ] = meshgrid(1:n, 1:n);
> ```

These are not necessary at all. Since MATLAB R2016b we have implicit singleton expansion, but before that you could use `bsxfun` to operate on two arrays of different sizes. So none of the following indexing operations are really necessary.

> ```
> P(i, j) = y1(i, j) .* y2(i, j) .* (data(i,:) * data(j,:)');
> ```

can be rewritten as

```
P = (y .* y.') .* (data * data.');
```

Note that I use `.'` here, where you had `'`. `'` is the complex conjugate transpose. Unless you want to compute a dot product, you should avoid it. `.'` transposes the matrix without changing any of its values. For real-valued data they're the same, but it's good to get used to using the right form, it will prevent difficult to find errors down the road.

> ```
> Aeq = y';
> ```

Same here: `y.'`.

> ```
> beq = [ 0 ];
> ```

Again, the MATLAB Editor warns here about the useless `[]` brackets. Heed the warnings!

There is actually no difference in MATLAB between a matrix and a scalar. A scalar is a matrix with a single value. The `[...]` operator is for concatenation. It concatenates two or more matrices into a single matrix. Every time you have a single matrix inside `[]`, the MATLAB Editor will warn you about it.

Similarly, I often see things like `[1:10]`. `1:10` is a matrix, the `[]` don't do anything there.

> ```
> w = (data' .* repmat(y', [space 1])) * alpha;
> ```

Same here: `data.'`, `y.'`.

> ```
> svIndices = find(alpha > threshold);
> b = y(svIndices(1)) - data(svIndices(1),:) * w;
> ```

Here you can use the second argument to `find` to tell it to give you only one index:

```
svIndex = find(alpha > threshold,1);
b = y(svIndex) - data(svIndex,:) * w;
```

> ```
> domain = (min(data(:,1)) - margin):(max(data(:,1)) + margin);
> ```

You don't need this many parentheses here, but they don't hurt either. I actually think they help readability. But the `:` has a much lower precedence than `+` and `-`. This should also work:

```
domain = min(data(:,1))-margin : max(data(:,1))+margin;
```

Comment: Thanks! All good thoughts, and answered the questions I had.